# ARCore : is arcore-preview.apk (= Tango Core app) required to run a ARCore app?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, google-project-tango, arcore, android-augmented-reality

I would like to develop an app using ARCore. I have several questions:

1. is it required to install the arcore-preview.apk  to be able to run this ARCore app ?
2. Why does the arcore-preview.apk appears with the name "Tango Core" in the applications list of my device ?
3. Will the Android OS directly include the ARCore (Tango Core ?) SDK in the future ?
4. Will all the devices be compatible with ARCore ? (not just the S8 and a few devices...)

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes
2. Because ARCore is based on the much older [Project Tango](https://get.google.com/tango/)
3. Unclear but likely - at least a Tango Core App downloadable from the play store
4. No. But much more than the current choice:

   > Google plans to add support for other phones from Samsung, Huawei, LG,
   >   and Asus, among others. The goal is to bring ARCore support to “100
   >   million devices at the end of the preview." - [source](https://liliputing.com/2017/08/google-arcore-brings-augmented-reality-android-phones-no-tango-hardware-required.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, If u using preview 1 then arcore-preview.apk else if you are using preview2 then install arcore-preview2.apk
2. ARCore is based on the Tango. The service name is display as Tango Core in preview 1 and the servie name is diplay as ARCore in Preview2
3. Yes, In future they have plan attach the services by default in sdk but not sure(In Progress) and now the Apps can be downloaded from Play Store.
4. Supported Devices are Following
   Google Pixel, Pixel XL, Pixel 2, Pixel 2 XL
   Samsung Galaxy S8 (SM-G950U, SM-G950N, SM-G950F, SM-G950FD, SM-G950W, SM-G950U1)

Some of the different in Preview 1 and 2

1. When another app opens in preview 1 it can be closed but preview 2 that can be handle(Example In coming call)
2. Display Rotation is auto handle in preview 2 (For Developers some cdes can be changed)
3. OpenGL is low level API So Advance Integration is some tricky for basic developers.

Future Enhancement
    All of the basic functionality an be handle in 1.0 (like as AR Kit)

Comment: Thanks for these details. May you give more details about point 3 (OpenGL) ? Do you mean that we do not need to use OpenGL anymore with preview 2 ?

Comment: OpenGl also use in Preview 2 Because Open Gl is base for Render the Object in 3D surfaceView

Answer (score 0):

> 1. is it required to install the arcore-preview.apk to be able to run this ARCore app ?

ARCore is no longer in developer preview as of the Feb. 23rd, 2018 [announcement](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/announcing-arcore-10-and-new-updates-to.html) of ARCore 1.0. The [ARCore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core) service is updated via the Play Store.

> 2. Why does the arcore-preview.apk appears with the name "Tango Core" in the applications list of my device ?

Now that ARCore is out of developer preview, *Tango Core* is obsolete / no longer relevant.

> 3. Will the Android OS directly include the ARCore (Tango Core ?) SDK in the future ?

[ARCore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core) is separate from the operating system, but supported devices typically come with a stub version pre-installed, which is then updated by the Play Store.

Links to the latest ARCore SDKs can be found on the downloads page:
[developers.google.com/ar/develop/downloads](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/downloads)

> 4. Will all the devices be compatible with ARCore ? (not just the S8 and a few devices...)

The list of supported ARCore devices (iOS and Android) is regularly updated. The official list is maintained as part of the developer documentation:
[developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices)